# Cosmos Java SDK throwing exceptions with x-ms-substatus=10002

Tags: java, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using Cosmos DB with Spring data

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

For some requests, (intermittently), we are seeing some errors like -

**1. Failed to upsert item; nested exception is CosmosException**

**2. Failed to find items; nested exception is CosmosException** : Item should be available for which the query was made.

**3. DocumentProducer - Unexpected failure**

```
{userAgent=azsdk-java-cosmos/4.8.0 Linux/5.3.0-1035-azure JRE/1.8.0_291, error=null, resourceAddress='null', requestUri='null', statusCode=0, message=null, {"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.8.0 Linux/5.3.0-1035-azure JRE/1.8.0_291","requestLatencyInMs":60073,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:31:17.150Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:32:17.223Z",
"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"retryCount":0,"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},
"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":[{"serializationType":"ITEM_SERIALIZATION","startTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:31:17.150Z","endTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:31:17.150Z","durationInMicroSec":0},{"serializationType":"PARTITION_KEY_FETCH_SERIALIZATION","startTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:31:17.150Z","endTimeUTC":"2021-06-25T05:31:17.150Z","durationInMicroSec":0}]},
"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Upsert","statusCode":0,"subStatusCode":10002,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"264619 KB","availableMemory":"3789909 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2021-06-25T05:31:50.445Z 2.0%), (2021-06-25T05:31:55.445Z 2.0%), 
(2021-06-25T05:32:00.445Z 2.0%), (2021-06-25T05:32:05.445Z 2.0%), (2021-06-25T05:32:10.445Z 2.0%), (2021-06-25T05:32:15.445Z 2.0%)"},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"numberOfClients":2,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},
"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [southcentralus,westus])"}}, 

causeInfo=[class: class io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException, message: null], responseHeaders={x-ms-substatus=10002}, requestHeaders=[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 25 Jun 2021 05:31:17 GMT, x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey=["xxxxx"], x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert=true, Content-Type=application/json]}
```

Stacktrace does not show much info, I can attach here if needed. In all these cases, we are seeing only one response header in the log -

```
responseHeaders={x-ms-substatus=10002}
```

We have below questions on this -

- What is the meaning of this status? Our Cosmos Help team is asking for Activityid which we are not able to find in the logs for these errors. How can I add the activityId in these cases too? I can't use ResponseDiagnosticsProcessor as it needs other spring cosmos dependency.
- What are the possible reason for these errors?
- In stacktrace, why all these are showing -
  `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException` also?
- How can we debug these errors?

**Note:**. We are not using Gremlin API and connecting in Gateway Mode AND we are seeing these errors very less, may be less than  0.05% of the total Cosmos requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substatus 10002 is related to HTTP timeouts. Since you are on Gateway mode, it makes sense that your operations are executing through HTTP.

When designing or coding a distributed application you always need to account for timeouts. The SDK does retry on timeouts (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-java-sdk-v4-sql#retry-logic-) but applications should always have some layer of timeout retries, since they can happen for various reasons (network blips, sporadic resource contention).

You mentioned that you see this less than 0.05% of total requests, which is not bad, but it's worth checking the areas in the guide for Java timeouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-request-timeout-java-sdk-v4-sql

Timeouts could also happen due to a service side latency spike (it's not likely but it can happen), and this is one area that the support team you mentioned might help. From the diagnostics, it looks like you have a request timeout of 5 seconds, so any Gateway requests with more than 5 second latency would generate one .

Comment: I have 2 more questions below - 

1. When Http Timeouts happen, then can we obtain the activity Id, is it? Just wanted to make sure, is there any scenario, where a query being fired which is taking a lot of time.

2. I am seeing a max of 200ms latency in Cosmos Server Latency dashboard. Can it still be a cause of timeouts?

3. I will be exploring the troubleshooting steps that you mentioned..

Thanks

Comment: One more question - 

If request is timing out, why I am seeing `{x-ms-substatus=10002}` when I am seeing the error message as 

`nested exception is com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.exception.CosmosAccessException: Failed to find items; nested exception is CosmosException`. 

Should not it be 404 status?

Comment: `{x-ms-substatus=10002}` means the request timed out sending or receiving the response, there is no activityId because the request might have never reached the service, if you look at the documentation for timeouts, there could be several things bottlenecking the machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-request-timeout-java-sdk-v4-sql. 
Because of this, if the source of the problem is the machine, you won't see any latency on the Dashboard, the problem is not on the account.
I don't know about spring exceptions enough to answer the second questions.